# Auto-sizing TextView does not size to fit updated text

Tags: android, textview, android-appcompat

I'm using an Android auto-sizing TextView via the appcompat library, as below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="14sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="0.5sp"
    android:text="@string/something" />
```

This works nicely the first time the text is set - eg the text size shrinks if it needs to.

But the second time it's set, the text size doesn't grow again if the content is small enough to allow it. It remains at the smaller size appropriate for the previous content.

So, what is the proper procedure for calling `setText` on an auto-sizing TextView, so that the auto-sizing parameters are respected? Or is there a way to force the TextView to re-evaluate its content and resize the text?

I have tried setting the text size back to the default before calling `setText` but that seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By reproducing your code I faced the same problem and the only solution that worked is giving a specific height to the TextView like:  `android:layout_height="30dp"`  
 From: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview#setting-textview-autosize

> If you set autosizing in an XML file, it is not recommended to use the
>   value "wrap_content" for the layout_width or layout_height attributes
>   of a TextView. It may produce unexpected results.